# Deleting in Smaller Quantities SQLAlchemy MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

MySQL table space tends to increase for large deletions.

I am currently doing:

```
s = session.query(model)
s.delete()
```

I understand that I can add

```
s.limit(1000)
```

and `sleep` after each deletion and re-querying `s.all()` to determine if all the entries have been wiped. Is there a way to just say delete in batches of `1000` until all the original records have been cleaned out?

Answer (score 0):

Your transaction log and required space is going to be huge if you're deleting a large number of records in a single transaction. If you need the transaction, this is unavoidable (refactor to not require it). Otherwise, call .commit() between smaller chunks of (say 100,000 or so) records.